# Streamlines on non-convex curved cartesian mesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot streamlines of a velocity field defined on a non-convex curved cartesian mesh.

Problem 1 : The matplotlib function streamplot only works with a grid
Solution : I'm forced to manually interpolate my velocity field on a grid.

Problem 2 : The interpolation only works on convex domain.
Solution : For the moment I'm adding a dummy cell in each direction, and setting my velocity field to np.nan.

This seems highly inefficient / troublesome.

I'm wondering if anyone has a better idea?

Here is an exemple :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Create dummy data
# In my case the curved mesh is much more complex
r = np.linspace(1,3,100)
theta = -np.linspace(np.pi,3*np.pi,100)

radius_matrix, theta_matrix = np.meshgrid(r,theta)

X_curv = np.zeros_like(radius_matrix)
Y_curv = np.zeros_like(radius_matrix)

X_curv[:50] = radius_matrix[:50] * np.cos(theta_matrix[:50])
Y_curv[:50] = radius_matrix[:50] * np.sin(theta_matrix[:50])

X_curv[50:] = 4 - radius_matrix[50:,::-1] * np.cos(theta_matrix[50:])
Y_curv[50:] = radius_matrix[50:,::-1] * np.sin(theta_matrix[50:])

U_theta = 1 - np.abs(radius_matrix - 2)

U_curv = U_theta * np.sin(theta_matrix)
V_curv = - U_theta * np.cos(theta_matrix)

U_curv[50:] *= -1

###########################################
# Now I just want to plot the streamlines #
###########################################

def interpol_and_plot(X_curv, Y_curv, U_curv, V_curv):
    """
    Interpolate the cuved data on a regular mesh, and plot the streamlines
    Am I really forced to interpolate ?
    """
    xmin, xmax = X_curv.min(), X_curv.max()
    ymin, ymax = Y_curv.min(), Y_curv.max()

    # create a grid of nxg * nyg points
    grid = np.mgrid[ymin:ymax:100j,xmin:xmax:100j][::-1]
    X_grid = grid[0,0,:]
    Y_grid = grid[1,:,0]

    # griddata want data in this shape
    mesh_curv = np.stack((X_curv, Y_curv), axis=-1).reshape((-1, 2))
    mesh_grid = np.rollaxis(grid, 0, 3).reshape((-1, 2))

    # interpolate
    U_grid = griddata(points=mesh_curv,
                      values=U_curv.flatten(),
                      xi=mesh_grid)
    V_grid = griddata(points=mesh_curv,
                      values=V_curv.flatten(),
                      xi=mesh_grid)

    U_grid = U_grid.reshape((100,100))
    V_grid = V_grid.reshape((100,100))

    # plot result
    plt.figure()
    plt.contourf(X_curv,Y_curv,U_curv)
    plt.streamplot(x=X_grid,
                   y=Y_grid,
                   u=U_grid,
                   v=V_grid,density=3)
    plt.show()


# Naive solution (that doesn't work)
interpol_and_plot(X_curv, Y_curv, U_curv, V_curv)

# A (bad) solution that work

nx, ny = X_curv.shape
X_curv2 = np.zeros((nx+2, ny+2))
Y_curv2 = np.zeros((nx+2, ny+2))
U_curv2 = np.zeros((nx+2, ny+2))
V_curv2 = np.zeros((nx+2, ny+2))

U_curv2[:] = np.nan
V_curv2[:] = np.nan
U_curv2[1:-1,1:-1] = U_curv
V_curv2[1:-1,1:-1] = V_curv

X_curv2[1:-1,1:-1] = X_curv
Y_curv2[1:-1,1:-1] = Y_curv

# new edge
X_curv2[0,1:-1] = 2 * X_curv2[1,1:-1] - X_curv2[2,1:-1]
X_curv2[-1,1:-1] = 2 * X_curv2[-2,1:-1] - X_curv2[-3,1:-1]
X_curv2[1:-1,0] = 2 * X_curv2[1:-1,1] - X_curv2[1:-1,2]
X_curv2[1:-1,-1] = 2 * X_curv2[1:-1,-2] - X_curv2[1:-1,-3]

Y_curv2[0,1:-1] = 2 * Y_curv2[1,1:-1] - Y_curv2[2,1:-1]
Y_curv2[-1,1:-1] = 2 * Y_curv2[-2,1:-1] - Y_curv2[-3,1:-1]
Y_curv2[1:-1,0] = 2 * Y_curv2[1:-1,1] - Y_curv2[1:-1,2]
Y_curv2[1:-1,-1] = 2 * Y_curv2[1:-1,-2] - Y_curv2[1:-1,-3]

# new corners
X_curv2[0,0] = (X_curv2[1,0] + X_curv2[0,1])*0.5
X_curv2[0,-1] = (X_curv2[1,-1] + X_curv2[0,-2])*0.5
X_curv2[-1,0] = (X_curv2[-2,0] + X_curv2[-1,1])*0.5
X_curv2[-1,-1] = (X_curv2[-2,-1] + X_curv2[-1,-2])*0.5

Y_curv2[0,0] = (Y_curv2[1,0] + Y_curv2[0,1])*0.5
Y_curv2[0,-1] = (Y_curv2[1,-1] + Y_curv2[0,-2])*0.5
Y_curv2[-1,0] = (Y_curv2[-2,0] + Y_curv2[-1,1])*0.5
Y_curv2[-1,-1] = (Y_curv2[-2,-1] + Y_curv2[-1,-2])*0.5

interpol_and_plot(X_curv2, Y_curv2, U_curv2, V_curv2)
```

And the results :
[image: The naive solution]
[image: A solution that works]

Comment: This is far too broad. Mock up a simple example with, e.g., 10x10 array, and show us what you're actually talking about with actual code.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a little while to produce this exemple, but here it is.